# can any one explain the below code in play framework?

Tags: java, playframework

can any one explain the code in play framework  I am new to play framework

```
public static void show(Long id) {

    AuctionItem item = AuctionItem.findById(id);

    render(item);
  }
```

Comment: Here we are passing a parameter id and we have to render the id but why we are rendering an item

Comment: Your little piece of code is part of a bigger picture, mate. Provide the appropriate context for your problem.

Comment: The whole code i can't understand that is my problem

Comment: Excuse me for asking. But do you know how to code?

Comment: No i am new to play framework

Comment: Looks like you're using Play v1.1.x.

Comment: Yes i am using play 1.2.4 version

Comment: @RAJARAM, sorry to say that, but you should choose another hobby :/ these are basics, and most of them are described in the oficial docs, you need to learn it first YOURSELF before going to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ID`of an `AuctionItem` that is created when you create an `AuctionItem`. The class `AuctionItem` has a static method that returns an `AuctionItem` depending on the `ID` in the argument. It then renders the `AuctionItem`.

Can't really be more specific without more information and detail.

Comment: AuctionItem item = AuctionItem.findById(id);//Here what is findById(id);

Comment: `findByID(id)` is a method call that returns an `AuctionItem` depending on the argument `id`